# Mootools Request.JSONP for Piwik Live.getVisitorProfile is giving null

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, mootools, matomo

website : "http://stage.artsocket.com"

My website is being tracked by Piwik and In my website to retrieve current visitors profile I am using "&method=Live.getVisitorProfile" and while retrieving the data, sometimes I am getting an empty json for first time visitor (a visitor visiting for first time) and if the same visitor visit the page again (refreshing the page) "&method=Live.getVisitorProfile" of Piwik is retrieving the json value.

I guess this is because of cookie being saved on client (visitor's) browser.

My implementation is to bring visitor's profile and identify whether is it a first time visitor or returning visitor, accordingly I have to play with my JavaScript.

"`var piwikUserDataFile = 'https://xx.xx.xx.xxx/piwik/index.php?module=API&method=Live.getVisitorProfile&visitorId=xxxxxxx&idSite=xx&format=json&token_auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';`"

```
new Request.JSONP({url: piwikUserDataFile, callbackKey: 'jsoncallback',log:'true', onComplete: function(data){ 
console.log("Before decoding:"+data); 
piwikDataDecode = JSON.decode(JSON.stringify(data)); 
console.log("After decoding:"+piwikDataDecode['lastVisits']); 

console.log("Visitor Type: "+piwikDataDecode['lastVisits'][0]['visitorType']); 
console.log("Referrer Name: "+piwikDataDecode['lastVisits'][0]['referrerName']); 
console.log("Device Type: "+piwikDataDecode['lastVisits'][0]['deviceType']); 
console.log("Country: "+piwikDataDecode['countries'][0]['prettyName']); 
console.log("Operating System Name: "+piwikDataDecode['lastVisits'][0]['operatingSystemName']); 
console.log("Browser Name: "+piwikDataDecode['lastVisits'][0]['browserName']); 

}).send();
```

This is how I am using the Live.getVisitorProfile() and retrieving JSONP value using Mootools Request.JSONP.

I am using Request.JSONP of MooTools (http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.5.2/Request/Request.JSONP)

This is acting sometimes with Win 10 + any browser. 
and someother times with Mac + any browser.

Sometimes Request.JSONP is returning JSON value on Mac eco-system on any browser and sometimes it isn't returning. Same is the case with Windows eco-system on any browser.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by "acting sometimes weird"? Is it possible to reproduce the problem with jsFiddle?

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific, by weird I mean sometimes on Mac with any browser is works and some other times it doesn't same is the case with Windows, I agree on the point that callbacks do steer these issues. I am not sure how can I reproduce with jsfiddle. All I can assure is if you visit "stage.artsocket.com" and inspect elements -> console output, there should be log (as mentioned in question) but as Request.JSONP is returning null, I am not getting the required output